# Is there a way to execute a program when a printer jams or runs out of paper

Tags: windows-7, printing, label-printer

Is there a way to execute a program when a printer jams or runs out of paper?

We have computers with touch screens that our members checkin on.  However, if the printer jams or runs out of paper, people can still checkin but won't get their name tag printed.

I want to be able to shutdown the checkin program if the printer is not working.

Comment: With network printers it is feasible to write something that uses SNMP to check the printer and spawn a program when the error occurs. Some printers can send an email when they have a problem, which could also trigger a program. This does not apply to USB or LPT printers.